# python selenium unable to locate a table id which exists

Tags: python, selenium, html-table

I would like to locate the "160528" element in the html code below:

```
<td class="calCell">
    <div id="cal1">
        <div align="center">
            <table id="table1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr></tr>
                        <td>
                            <a id="160528"></a>
                        </td>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

what I did is:

```
calCell = driver.find_element_by_class_name('calCell')
cal1 = calCell.find_element_by_id('cal1')
table1 = cal1.find_element_by_id('table1')
```

The program will complain "Unable to locate element", nevertheless the table1 truly exists.

Is there anyone can share some lights on how to locate the 160528? Is there any easier approach other than go to sub-element one by one?

Comment: have you tried ```item = driver.find_element_by_id("160528")```

Comment: yep, i did try that. but selenium seems cannot locate any item in the sub element :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table might not be present when you search for it. Add a wait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
table1 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".calCell #cal1 #table1")))
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe. I am sorry for my typo. what I did for calCell is find_element_by_class_name(). But still I couldn't locate the "160528" :(

Comment: Unbelievable, it's the delay caused the table is not accessible. You nailed it again!!! Thank god I don't need to waster more time during this weekend to debug this issue :)